# How to handle permissions of an application that accesses a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an application that accesses a database directly. This application controls what user can do according to the context.

At the moment, I am using Windows authentication, but all the users has permissions to select, insert, update and delete, because it is the application which controls the action.

For example, one user can modify a document, but only if the document is created by this user. So in the database the user has to have permissions to create a update, but only if it is the owner of the document. I am not sure if I can handle this case with SQL Server user roles.

But the problem is that all users have all the permissions to the database, so they could use another application, like SQL Server Management Studio, to access the database and do what they want.

So I was thinking in the option to use SQL Server authentication, with full access to the database. This user is not known by users, so they can't use another applications to modify the database.

The problem that I see with this solution is that I have to store the credentials in the client application, and I don't know if it is really a secure way to do it.

If using SQL Server authentication is an good option, how could I store the credentials of the user in a safe way?

I have read about application roles too, but it is needed to store the password in the client application, so I think I would have the same problem. And also I don't see the difference between application role and to use SQL Server authentication.

In summary, is it a good solution to use SQL Server authentication in the way I explained above? And if it is a good option, how could I store credentials in a safe way?

Thanks.

Comment: password can be stored in databse as well

Comment: This might be an option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @viveknuna How could I store the password in the database?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía just explore store password in secure way in database, you will get idea

Comment: I have read in the past about how to stored the hashed password in the database. I don't know if you mean that. But if this, if I am not wrong, it is still needed to send the password to the server, the server hash the password and compare it with the stored hash. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between an [application role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/application-roles?view=sql-server-ver15) and using SQL Auth is that the application role password is not enough, by itself, to access the database.  The user must be individually authorized first and can be individually monitored and audited.

> how could I store the credentials of the user in a safe way?

The application role (or SQL Auth) password is never truly secure when used from a client application running on a machine where the user is an administrator.  So you could run the app in desktop virtualization, or a kiosk-mode PC.

But for many scenarios involving mostly-trusted users application role security is good enough, especially when combined with Windows Integrated auth so the users access to the database can be audited.